# Find if two trees are isomorphic

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Two trees can be called isomorphic if they have similar structure and the only difference amongst them can be is, that their child nodes may or may not be swapped. For example:

```
     4                 4
   /   \             /   \
  2     6    and    6     2
 / \   / \         / \   / \
1   3 5   7       1   3 7   5
```

The following code is supposed to be correct implementation which I found in the web, but for some reason it is not working for the above trees. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{

public:

    Node * left;
    Node * right;
    int val;

    Node(int v){
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        val = v;    
    }
};

bool isIsomorphic(Node* n1, Node *n2)
{
 // Both roots are NULL, trees isomorphic by definition
 if (n1 == NULL && n2 == NULL)
    return true;

 // Exactly one of the n1 and n2 is NULL, trees not isomorphic
 if (n1 == NULL || n2 == NULL)
    return false;

 if (n1->val != n2->val)
    return false;

 // There are two possible cases for n1 and n2 to be isomorphic
 // Case 1: The subtrees rooted at these nodes have NOT been "Flipped".
 // Both of these subtrees have to be isomorphic, hence the &&
 // Case 2: The subtrees rooted at these nodes have been "Flipped"
 return
 (isIsomorphic(n1->left,n2->left) && isIsomorphic(n1->right,n2->right))||
 (isIsomorphic(n1->left,n2->right) && isIsomorphic(n1->right,n2->left));
}

int main()
{
Node * na_4 = new Node(4);
Node * na_2 = new Node(2);
Node * na_6 = new Node(6);
Node * na_1 = new Node(1);
Node * na_3 = new Node(3);
Node * na_5 = new Node(5);
Node * na_7 = new Node(7);

na_4->left = na_2;
na_4->right = na_6;

na_2->left = na_1;
na_2->right = na_3;

na_6->left = na_5;
na_6->right = na_7;


Node * nb_4 = new Node(4);
Node * nb_6 = new Node(6);
Node * nb_2 = new Node(2);
Node * nb_1 = new Node(1);
Node * nb_3 = new Node(3);
Node * nb_7 = new Node(7);
Node * nb_5 = new Node(5);

nb_4->left = nb_6;
nb_4->right = nb_2;

nb_6->left = nb_1;
nb_6->right = nb_3;

nb_2->left = nb_7;
nb_2->right = nb_5;


if(isIsomorphic(na_4, nb_4)){
    cout << "Yes they are isomorphic" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "No there are not isomorphic" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

It outputs that they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those trees aren't isomorphic according to the definition you provided. A similar definition that's specific to binary trees also appears [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-isomorphism-problem/):

> Two trees are called isomorphic if one of them can be obtained from other by a series of flips, i.e. by swapping left and right children of a number of nodes. Any number of nodes at any level can have their children swapped. Two empty trees are isomorphic.

The problem is that in the one tree, 2 has children 1 and 3, but in the other tree, 2 has children 7 and 5.

By "swapping" two children, you actually need to swap their entire subtrees, not just the individual nodes and leaving all others where they are.

These two, for example, would be isomorphic:

```
     4
   /   \
  2     6
 / \   / \
1   3 5   7

     4
   /   \
  6     2
 / \   / \
7   5 1   3
```

---

**Note:** Some definitions of isomorphism ignore vertex labels (for more general [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) at least, in principle the same idea would apply to trees as well). Under those definitions, the trees given in the question would be isomorphic. I believe the definition given above would still apply if you ignore vertex labels. For graph isomorphism (as opposed to tree isomorphism, which takes the root into account), this would not work as general graphs have no concept of a root (trees produced by the above technique would still be graph isomorphic, but not all graphs isomorphisms can be produced using this technique).

Comment: In a graph theory sense, the two trees provided are isomorphic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism. How would flipping children generalize to n-ary trees?

Comment: @Iain Edited. According to some definitions, the given trees would be isomorphic. According to others, and specifically the definition given in the question, they aren't. This is mentioned under "Isomorphism of labeled graphs" on [the Wikipedia link you provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). You can freely rearrange the children / swap any number of children of a node in an n-ary tree in the same way you swap the two children of a node in a binary tree: you just need to swap their entire subtrees.

Comment: It is also important to node that this swapping method can be used to show that graphs/trees are isomorphic, but does not mean that two graphs/trees that are isomorphic can be shown to be as such through this method. Basically even in a general case for graphs this works, but unless stated explicitly otherwise, does not disqualify graphs from being isomorphic.

Comment: @Iain Do you have a counter-example that shows this method doesn't work for all isomorphic trees (assuming isomorphism which preserves/considers both labels and roots)? Although this seems to be a definition of isomorphism, so at worst it can be inconsistent with other definitions of isomorphism.

Comment: I suppose this is where the definition of a tree isomorphism differs from a graph isomorphism. I am not privy to the rule of preserving the root node. Consider the tree with 3 vertices of height 2 and another tree with 3 vertices with height 3. These are isomorphic, but cannot be shown to be isomorphic by flipping the lhs or rhs of the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

These given trees are not isomorphic. Two trees are called isomorphic if and only if one of them can be obtained from other by a series of flips, i.e. by swapping left and right children of a number of nodes. Also, any number of nodes at any level can have their children swapped.